# JDBC problem while connecting to data base

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc

the exception indicates that the driver is unknown while it exists in the lib of the web-inf directory.

any help please? [JDB driver problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJsc7.png)

Comment: hello Mark !! maybe the same problem but  they are the same solution!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

instead of

```
Class.forName ("com.sql.jdbc.Driver");
```

However I would recommend to use a DataSource in java EE (see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jdbc-pool.html)

Comment: it works Maksim, thank you. but i obtained another exception about the time zone..

Comment: Which type of exception ? Can you share it and post some code ?

Comment: "java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Paris, Madrid' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support."

Comment: Unfortunately the connect string is not viewable in your screenshot (therefore I just can guess) but probably you should replace the setting of  serverTimezone to `&serverTimezone=Europe/Paris`

Comment: the connection instruction are as below "Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ma_base", "root", "admin");"  Where did i have to add "&serverTimezone=Europe/Paris"? thank you in advance

Comment: Try this: `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ma_base?serverTimezone=Europe/Paris", "root", "admin")`. However it seems like your mysqld is misconfigured....

Comment: the only error message that still appear is "Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary" otherwise all others are OK !!

Comment: Then you know what to do. Congrats. :-)

Comment: yes, all works perfectly, thank you a lot Maksim, you are a Great person !!